# Android command not working

Tags: android

I am writing a code in which I am trying to open up the camera of the device but my command is not working , it is showing compiletime error , Please see that is the command correct or is it wrong and if it is wrong then please provide me the correct code , this is my code -

```
Camera camera= Camera.open();
```

Comment: Try reading this... http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: compiletime error? what is that?

Comment: @DheereshSingh It says open() function is undefined .

Comment: Isn't there any predefined function like open() .

Comment: make sure u are importing `import android.hardware.Camera;` package in you class?

Comment: Why can't we use both these header files at the same time      import android.hardware.Camera;                               import android.graphics.Camera;

Comment: yes you can use both packages but when you u are using both in same class then refer one of them  as `android.hardware.Camera camera= android.hardware.Camera.open();` instead of `Camera camera= Camera.open();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this -

```
import android.hardware.Camera;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have added but just FYI

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

and please look over the [link](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html) .......

if not work try all these once

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28%29) it should work.

You can pass an Intent to initiate the Camera and take the picture  like

```
private Uri imageUri;

public void takePhoto(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  "Pic.jpg");
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
            Uri.fromFile(photo));
    imageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
    case TAKE_PICTURE:
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageUri;
            getContentResolver().notifyChange(selectedImage, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            Bitmap bitmap;
            try {
                 bitmap = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media
                 .getBitmap(cr, selectedImage);

                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                Toast.makeText(this, selectedImage.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to load", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```